# OpenMP and (Rcpp)Eigen

Tags: parallel-processing, openmp, eigen

I am wondering how to write code that at times makes use of OpenMP parallelization built into the Eigen library while at other times uses Parallelization that I specify. Hopefully, the below code snippet should provide background into my problem.
I am asking this question at the design stage of my library (sorry I don't have a working / broken code example).

```
#ifdef _OPENMP
  #include <omp.h>
#endif

#include <RcppEigen.h>

void fxn(..., int ncores=-1){
  if (ncores > 0) omp_set_num_threads(ncores);
  /*
  * Code with matrix products 
  * where I would like to use Eigen's 
  * OpenMP parallelization
  */ 

  #pragma omp parallel for
  for (int i=0; i < iter; i++){
  /* 
  * Code I would like to parallelize "myself"
  * even though it involves matrix products
  */
  }
}
```

What is best practice for controlling the balance between Eigen's own parallelization with OpenMP and my own.

## UPDATE:

I wrote a simple example and tested ggael's suggestion. In short, I am skeptical that it solves the problem I was posing (or I am doing something else wrong - apologies if its the latter). Notice that with explicit parallelization of the for loop there is no change in run-time (not even a slow

```
#ifdef _OPENMP
  #include <omp.h>
#endif 
#include <RcppEigen.h>

using namespace Rcpp;
// [[Rcpp::plugins(openmp)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Eigen::MatrixXd testing(Eigen::MatrixXd A, Eigen::MatrixXd B, int n_threads=1){
  Eigen::setNbThreads(n_threads);
  Eigen::MatrixXd C = A*B;
  Eigen::setNbThreads(1);
  for (int i=0; i < A.cols(); i++){
    A.col(i).array() = A.col(i).array()*B.col(i).array(); 
  }
  return A;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Eigen::MatrixXd testing_omp(Eigen::MatrixXd A, Eigen::MatrixXd B, int n_threads=1){
  Eigen::setNbThreads(n_threads);
  Eigen::MatrixXd C = A*B;
  Eigen::setNbThreads(1);
  #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(n_threads)
  for (int i=0; i < A.cols(); i++){
    A.col(i).array() = A.col(i).array()*B.col(i).array(); 
  }
  return A;
}


/*** R
A <- matrix(rnorm(1000*1000), 1000, 1000)
B <- matrix(rnorm(1000*1000), 1000, 1000)
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(testing(A,B, n_threads=1),
                               testing_omp(A,B, n_threads=1),
                               testing(A,B, n_threads=8), 
                               testing_omp(A,B, n_threads=8), 
                               times=10)
*/

Unit: milliseconds
                             expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval cld
     testing(A, B, n_threads = 1) 169.74272 183.94500 212.83868 218.15756 236.97049 264.52183    10   b
 testing_omp(A, B, n_threads = 1) 166.53132 178.48162 210.54195 227.65258 234.16727 238.03961    10   b
     testing(A, B, n_threads = 8)  56.03258  61.16001  65.15763  62.67563  67.37089  83.43565    10  a 
 testing_omp(A, B, n_threads = 8)  54.18672  57.78558  73.70466  65.36586  67.24229 167.90310    10  a
```

Comment: Really not an Rcpp question.  That is between you and Eigen.  Maybe remove the `rcpp` tag?

Comment: Good point. I don’t seem to be able to do that though. Sorry!

Comment: Strange, you should be able to [edit] your post including the tags. Anyway, I removed the tag for now ...

Comment: As Ralf stresses, you can _always_ edit your own posts.

Comment: I could not seem to on a mobile device. I assumed that was a permissions issue.

Comment: Your results look perfectly normal to me as the cost is entirely dominated by the matrix product which has a n^3 complexity compared to n^2 for your loop.

Comment: Moreover, your loop is not doing any matrix products but coefficient-wise products that are not parallelized by Eigen anyway. So disabling Eigen's multithreading for this loop or not won't make any difference. BTW, your for loop can also directly be written as `A.array() *= B.array();`

Answer (score 4):

The easiest is probably to disable/enable Eigen's multi-threading at runtime:

```
Eigen::setNbThreads(1); // single thread mode
#pragma omp parallel for
for (int i=0; i < iter; i++){ 
  // Code I would like to parallelize "myself"
  // even though it involves matrix products
}
Eigen::setNbThreads(0); // restore default
```

Comment: I updated my question with an example using this suggestion. In short, I don't think it solves the problem. My apologies if I have made a mistake or not interpreted your answer correctly.